# How can I organize a million+ files now that I'm moving to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

Well I'm getting booted from my shared host and I'm switching over to a combination of a VPS from [Linode](http://linode.com) and Amazon S3 to host a few million jpegs.

My big worry is keeping some kind of sanity with all these images.  Is there any hope of that?  My understanding is you're only allowed 100 "buckets" and "buckets" are the only type of structure within S3.

Is putting a few million files in a bucket something you'd advise against?

Comment: - [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)
- [Amazon S3 bucket limit](http://seocracy.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-bucket-limit/)

Answer (score 6):

You may notice in [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html), it is stated:

```
There is no limit to the number of objects that can be stored in a bucket
```

My experience is that a very large number of objects in a single bucket will not affect the performance of getting a single object by its key (that is, get appears to be of constant complexity).

Having a very large number of object also [does not affect the speed of listing a given number of objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html):

```
List performance is not substantially affected by the total number of keys in your bucket
```

However, I must warn you, that most S3 management tools I've used (like S3Fox) will choke and die a horrible slow death when attempting to access a bucket with a very large number of objects.  One tool that seems to cope well with very large numbers of objects is [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/) (they have a free version and a Pro version, I am not affiliated with them in any way).

Using "folders" or prefixes, does not change any of these points (get and listing a given number of objects are still constant, most tools still fall over themselves and hang).

Comment: Ya you pretty much summed up my sentiments, it's all fun and games to upload 10 million files, but once they're up there you're pretty much stuck with them forever since there's no breakdowns and any listing tool won't be able to handle that large a list.

Comment: Well definitely check out S3 Browser.  Prefixes/folders can be of some help but they don't reduce the number of objects in the bucket.  Really, it's up to you to implement another sort of list - usually records in a db with the filenames/urls - and manage the objects off of that.

Comment: ya that's what I'm gonna do I just hate the idea that if there's a bug in my code I end up having to pay for it forever -- literally.

Comment: I've successfully used s3cmd : http://s3tools.org/s3cmd to list the content of buckets containing 100k's of images - runs directly from a server so benefits from fast net connection, can pipe the output to a file etc.

Comment: My understanding is that S3 hashes object keys, so that lookup time for a given object is O(1).   But what is the expected time for a call to AmazonS3.listObjects *that match a prefix of a key*? The documentation for `AmazonS3.listObjects` says ```The total number of keys in a bucket doesn't substantially affect list performance.```
But how is that possible unless they index *prefixes*  of keys?   I asked AWS engineers for more guidance and they dodged the question and just said that calling `listObjects` can be slow.  I wonder if it does a linear search.

Comment: @DonSmith I cannot say definitively, but I would guess based on my experience (though I don't do a ton of prefix matching) that there is no prefix index and listing object that match a prefix is O(n) where n is the number of objects in the bucket in total.

Comment: Amazon _used_ to recommend prepending a random or varying string to keys, to improve performance: to better distribute objects in partitions/buckets.  That suggests that they use(d) hashing.   They no longer recommend prepending:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html .  Perhaps they *do* use b-trees or some such O(log(n)) data structure; if so, then, presumably, listObjects by prefix would be fast.   The AWS documentation is vague about how it works. Perhaps it's just super-parallelized.  Knowing expected performance would guide our use of it.